# Find specific values within a column and copy the entire row of data to a new sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I am working on vba code for a project where I have data (for Slope Inclinometers) in the "Data Importation Sheet." I then require the user to insert a value (depth) for at which they will want calculations to be completed at that specified value. When the user inserts a value for depth I want the vba code to find all of the cells within column A of "Data Importation Sheet" that contain that value and copy the corresponding rows into the next worksheet "Calculations." For example if the user input a depth of 3.5, I want the code to find all cells within Column A that contain 3.5 and copy the data within that row into the "Calculations" worksheet.

Currently the code I have does the following:
If the user inputs 3.5, the data for values 3.5, 13.5, 23.5, 35.5, etc all appear in the "Calculations" Worksheet. Or if the user inputs 2, the data for values 2, 2.5, 12, 12.5, 20, etc appear. I only want the data corresponding to the exact number input by the user! Here is the code I have:

```
Sub FindMe()
  Dim A As String
  Dim i As Integer
  Dim j As Integer
  Dim strsearch As String
  Dim lastline As Integer
  Dim lastrow As Integer

  A = Worksheets("Data Importation Sheet").Cells(15, "W").Value
  Worksheets("Hidden").Cells(1, "C") = A
  Worksheets("Calculations").Activate
  lastrow = Worksheets("Calculations").Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).row
  j = lastrow
  Worksheets("Data Importation Sheet").Activate
  lastline = Range("A65536").End(xlUp).row
  strsearch = Cells.Find(A, LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlWhole)
  For i = 1 To lastline
    For Each c In Range("A" & i)
      If InStr(c, strsearch) Then
        tocopy = 1
      End If
    Next c
    If tocopy = 1 Then
      Rows(i).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Calculations").Rows(j)
      j = j + 1
    End If
    tocopy = 0
  Next i
End Sub
```

Any tips/help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: How is your data laid out in the Data Importation sheet? Does each column represent a set of measurements at various depths and each row represent a particular depth?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
If InStr(" " & c.Text & " ", " " & strsearch & " ") Then
```

This will match a whole word. You can set `strsearch` a priori as `strsearch = " " & A & " "` outside the loop (to go faster).

Finally I dont see the point of this statement:

```
strsearch = Cells.Find(A, LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlWhole)
```

It looks equivalent to a direct assignment `strsearch = A`.